# How to make and edit an Html div in javascript

Tags: javascript, append

Trying to make an Html div inside a div that is already made using javascript but my function has a problem.

Html part

```
<div id="test">
<button onclick="addDiv()">test</button>
</div>
```

Js part

```
let page = document.querySelector('test');

function addDiv() {
    document.createElement('div')
    document.querySelector('page')
    addedDiv = document.appendChild('div')
    page = document.appendChild('div')
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = "ThisFunctionIsWorking"
}
```

the output should be seen in the console with a text inside the div that says ThisFunctionIsWorking
but instead I get an error(Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.)

I would appreciate your time helping me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrect in many ways. I suggest you study basic (web) programming with the emphasis on fundamentals like return values, scope, etc. and then basic javascript and dom tree manipulation.

A solution to your problem is:

```
<div id="test">
<button onclick="addDiv('test')">test</button>
</div>

function addDiv(nodeId) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div')
    var container = document.getElementById(nodeId)
    container.appendChild(elem)
    elem.innerHTML = "ThisFunctionIsWorking"
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot !! I am still a beginner and I am learning